# Trimming NSString with multiple conditions

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I'm having a hard time with trimming some characters from a NSString.  Given an existing text view with text in it, the requirements are:

1. Trim leading spaces and newlines (Basically ignore any leading whitespace and newlines)
2. Copy up to max of 48 chars into the new string OR until a newline is encountered.

I have found that I could do the first requirement from another SO question here with the code:

```
NSRange range = [textView.text rangeOfString:@"^\\s*" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
NSString *result = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
```

However, I'm having trouble with doing the 2nd requirement.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what your looking to do. Also it is an easier way to trim leading whitespace and newlines.

```
NSString *text = textView.text;

//remove any leading or trailing whitespace or line breaks
text = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

//find the the range of the first occuring line break, if any.
NSRange range = [text rangeOfString:@"\n"];

//if there is a line break, get a substring up to that line break
if(range.location != NSNotFound)
    text = [text substringToIndex:range.location];
//else if the string is larger than 48 characters, trim it
else if(text.length > 48)
    text = [text substringToIndex:48];
```

Comment: +1 but I think that he wants 48 characters or the newline, **whichever is less**.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Basically what it does is it loops through the characters in the text of the textview and checks if the character it's currently on is a newline character. It also checks if it has reached 48 characters yet. If the character is not a new line character and it has not reached 48 characters yet, then it adds the character to a result string:

```
NSString *resultString = [NSString string];
NSString *inputString = textView.text;

for(int currentCharacterIndex = 0; currentCharacterIndex < inputString.length; currentCharacterIndex++) {

    unichar currentCharacter = [inputString characterAtIndex:currentCharacterIndex];
    BOOL isLessThan48 = resultString.length < 48;
    BOOL isNewLine = (currentCharacter == '\n');

    //If the character isn't a new line and the the result string is less then 48 chars
    if(!isNewLine && isLessThan48) {

        //Adds the current character to the result string
        resultString = [resultString stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", currentCharacter]];
    } 

    //If we've hit a new line or the string is 48 chars long, break out of the loop
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```